# How to check HTTP request header for certain endpoints in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a simple Spring Boot REST service for the [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) platform. Each authorized request will contain a header `IFTTT-Service-Key` with my account's service key and I will use that to either process the request or return a 401 (Unauthorized). However, I only want to do this for select endpoints -- and specifically not for ANY of the Spring actuator endpoints.

I have looked into Spring Security, using filters, using `HandlerInterceptors`, but none seem to fit what I am trying to do exactly. Spring security seems to come with a lot of extra stuff (especially the default user login), filters don't really seem to match the use case, and the handler interceptor works fine but I would have to code logic in to watch specific URLs and ignore others.

What is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

For reference, this is the code I have now:

```
public class ServiceKeyValidator implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final String myIftttServiceKey;

    public ServiceKeyValidator(@Value("${ifttt.service-key}") String myIftttServiceKey) {
        this.myIftttServiceKey = myIftttServiceKey;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // TODO will have to put logic in to skip this when actuator endpoints are added

        String serviceKeyHeader = request.getHeader("IFTTT-Service-Key");

        if (!myIftttServiceKey.equals(serviceKeyHeader)) {
            var error = new Error("Incorrect value for IFTTT-Service-Key");
            var errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(Collections.singletonList(error));
            throw new UnauthorizedException(errorResponse);
        }
        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add filtering for the required endpoints in the place where you register your `HandlerInterceptor`.

For example:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(
            new ServiceKeyValidator())
                .addPathPatterns("/ifttt/**")
                .excludePathPatterns("/actuator/**");
    }

}
```

You can use different URLs path matchers to filter which URL endpoints must be handled by your interceptor and which are not. As the method [addPathPatterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistry.html#addInterceptor-org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor-) returns [InterceptorRegistration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html) object that configures this.